# wrong offset in relative position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this markup.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="imgsrc.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="imgsrc.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

With `.col-md-4` has relative position, when I try to attach mouseover event to the `.col-md-4` and get position of its offset it's return wrong offset for second `.col-md-4` in second row. Here is the script

```
$('.col-md-4').hover(function(){
    var offset = $(this).position();
    var height = $(this).height();
    console.log(offset); // this gives the wrong offset when hovering over second col-md-4 in second row
    $('#shadow2').stop(true, true).animate({
        'left': offset.left,
        'top': offset.top + height + 10
    });
}, function(){
    $('#shadow2').animate({
        'left': '-350px'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), it gives position of element relative to document, change

```
var offset = $(this).position();
```

to

```
var offset = $(this).offset();
```

**Update::**

```
$('.col-md-4').hover(function(){
    var childPosition = $(this).offset();
    var parentPosition = $(this).parent().offset();
    var actualOffset = {
        top: childPosition.top - parentPosition.top,
        left: childPosition.left - parentPosition.left
    }
    var height = $(this).height();
    console.log(offset);
    $('#shadow2').stop(true, true).animate({
        'left': actualOffset.left,
        'top': actualOffset.top + height + 10
    });
....
```

Comment: alredy used that, offset give position relative to document not to wrapper, in this case `.row`